# Reimplementing system() locally to prevent issues with blocking SIGCHLD on other threads

Tags: c, multithreading, shell, signals

I have had an issue with the `system()` call, since it was being used in a multithreaded context. My issue was that I would call `system()` to run a shell script in one thread, and simultaneously in a different thread I would also run a similar script using `system()`. The first `system()` call blocks `SIGCHLD`, and then the other script then inherits the blocked `SIGCHLD` signal in the child process (not 100% certain on this, but I know that `SIGCHLD` is somehow being blocked iff `system()` is run simultaneously). This causes some issues for me, since the shell script uses the `wait` builtin, which in my case relies on a signal being received from the child of that process.

My solution to this was to make a copy of `system()` locally, which does not block `SIGCHLD`.  This works well, but I am not sure if not blocking `SIGCHLD` has any other adverse side effects. I have seen that `SIGIGN` and `SIGQUIT` are also ignored in the parent process for the standard `system()` function.

> During execution of the command, SIGCHLD will be blocked, and SIGINT and SIGQUIT
> will  be  ignored, in the process that calls system() ...

My main process currently does not touch the `SIGCHLD`, `SIGINT` or `SIGQUIT` signals, so they are set to the default handlers. Also, the process is not used interactively, so a signal will not be propagated from the child process from a terminal.

Are there any other important reasons to block/ignore these signals?

I have included some abstracted code below to help contextualize.

main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

static int
system_local (char *filename, int nargs, ...)
{
    int pid;
    int status = -1;

    pid = fork ();
    if (pid < 0)    /* Error */
    {
        return -1;
    }
    else if (pid == 0)  /* Child: execute program */
    {
        va_list va_args;
        char **args = malloc ((nargs + 2) * sizeof (char *));
        int i;

        if (!args)
        {
            exit (-1);
        }

        args[0] = filename;
        va_start (va_args, nargs);
        /* Arguments are only used starting from args[1] */
        for (i = 1; i < nargs + 1; i++)
        {
            args[i] = va_arg (va_args, char *);
        }
        /* Must be NULL terminated */
        args[i] = NULL;

        /* Run the program */
        status = execvp (filename, (char *const *) args);

        /* Not reached */
        free (args);
        va_end (va_args);
        exit (status);
    }
    /* Otherwise this is the parent, so collect the exit status */
    else if (waitpid (pid, &status, 0) != -1 && WIFEXITED (status))
    {
        return WEXITSTATUS (status);
    }

    return -1;
}

void *thread_func(void *vargp)
{
    int ret;
    sleep(1);
    ret = system_local ("script.sh", 1, "child_thread");
    if (ret == 0)
    {
        printf ("Successful child thread!");
    }
    return NULL;
}
   
int main()
{
    int ret;
    pthread_t thread_id;
    pthread_create(&thread_id, NULL, thread_func, NULL);
    ret = system_local ("script.sh", 1, "main_thread");
    if (ret == 0)
    {
        printf ("Successful main thread!");
    }
    pthread_join(thread_id, NULL);
    exit(0);
}
```

script.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Starting script on $1"

# Using sleep to emulate running another script
sleep 100 &
PID=$!

wait $PID

echo "Finishing script on $1"
```